# Bootstrap-select randomly selects values on Safari (Mobile)

Tags: mobile-safari, bootstrap-select

I have a strange issue with Bootstrap-select on Safari for mobile (iOS). When selecting an option, it will sometimes select the wrong option. Like if I select "Apple" it will randomly select "Zebra". Does anyone know of this problem and have a solution?

Comment: We have a similar issue: when tapping a list item, e.g. BMW, the select would close but display AUDI as the selected option.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?